# Screen Stays Black After Idle

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, 20.10, idle

I had some old parts laying around and thought I'd put them to use in the living room as an HTPC. There's nothing special about the build, it's an mATX board with an Intel i5, 16GB of RAM, and no dedicated video card (full specs below). No issues with setup or anything, and other than the issue mentioned in the title it runs fine.

So for a bit more info on the problem, this only seems to happen when the system sits idle for a bit and the display turns off. After this happens there is a good chance that I won't be getting back into the machine as the screen stays black no matter what I do, and the only real option is to press and hold the power button until the machine shuts down. When the screen is black, I cannot access VTE either. Maybe it's working but because the screen stays black I can't say for sure. Adding to the strangeness I will usually get a no signal message from my TV after the shutdown. I can shutdown and power back up all day long and nothing will change. I have to let the system sit for several minutes for any hope of something displaying on the TV. I have other devices connected to this same TV and none of them have ever experience anything like this. I tested all HDMI ports on the TV and had the same results each time. Other than setting Ubuntu to not turn off the display after a set time of no activity, what can I do? Are there any logs I can check to help troubleshoot this? The issue exists on both Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10 x64.

**Full system specs:**
Intel DB85FL motherboard,
Intel i5 4430,
16GB RAM

Comment: There's a workaround for me, which is to press ALT CTRL F7 to go to another TTY then ALT CTRL F1 to go to the original. I see that the login screens are kinda duplicated. I log in one all violet background but after I press Enter I see the screen with my background for log in. But then it closes at I logged in in the other screen